# Print scaled image c#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to print image with this code.

```
   private void Print()
     {
         PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
         printDocument.PrintPage += PrintDocument_PrintPage;

         PrintPreviewDialog printDialog = new PrintPreviewDialog();
         printDialog.Document = printDocument;

         DialogResult result = printDialog.ShowDialog();
         if (result == DialogResult.OK) printDocument.Print();

         printDocument.PrintPage -= PrintDocument_PrintPage;
     }

     private void PrintDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
     {
      //e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, e.PageBounds.X, e.PageBounds.Y);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, e.PageBounds.X, e.PageBounds.Y, 
             e.PageBounds.Width, e.PageBounds.Height);
     }
```

When image is small it prints fine, but when its hi-rez (I have image 992*1403) it draws with wrong size.
When I view `PreviewDialog` or draw it to the *pdf file* it prints fine, but when I print it on printer it prints wrong sized.

Fixed my problem with this code:

e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Width,       e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Height);

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but how will the application know the `PageBounds` without knowing what type of paper you are printing on?

Have you tried setting your paper size to a specific size using something like this:

```
printDocument .DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = 
                new PaperSize("Custom", someWidth, someHeight);
```